# Is this multi-tenant database design is good

Tags: sql, database, database-design, ef-code-first

I am working on a multi-tenant website project. This project will manage the appointments for the tenants. Like a Hair dresser may be a tenant for this project. So hair dresser tenant have staff and Customers associated with it.Each customer will be served by any one staff member.

I have a question about the database design for this type of scenario. In this scenario i have 3 entity namely:

- Tenant
- Staff
- Customer (Customer is the user for the tenant)

First i will tell you about my thought for such database design and then i wants your expert advice.

**What i thought is:**

For me **Tenant**, **Staff** and **Customer** are all belongs to a same category so i have decided a single table for all of them *(Say User)*. This table contains a **TypeId** column which will differentiate between three of them. This table contains a self-referencing relationship for **Tenant-Staff** and **Tenant-Customer** which may be **1 to many**.

Visual Representation of my thought:

[image]

I am not good in database design and i want my database design as good as possible and **extendable**. So i am here to ask you guys please review my design and tell me the pros and cons of this design for this scenario and please suggest me a better design, if there is any other, for the scenario i mentioned above.

*And BTW i am using Entity Framework Code First in my project.*

Thanks.

Comment: Are customers or staff going to be logging in?

Comment: @cHao staffs are not going to be logged in but customers are. But in future may be we add staff loggin also.

Comment: You might  as well, considering that their all being in the same category means additional work to *avoid* a staff login...

Comment: If customers log in, will they be  able to see all the tennants they are associcated with or will each one havea separate login to an entirely differnt site?

Comment: No customer will not able to see all tenants, they will be associated with a single tenant at a time. And yes they each one have a separate login, but not on entirely different site, its just a virtual partitioning of a same application like if my project main site url is `www.appointments.com` than Foo tenant will have its separate space on `Foo.appointments.com` from where its customers will login and create appointments.

Answer (score 1):

The customers table will hold information specific to customers. In my example data we see that Mary and Greg are customers. Instead of storing first_name, last_name, etc. here I simply store a foreign key to the `users` table. I do this because we may have a user who is both a Customer AND an Employee (staff) - why would we want to make them create more than one sign on? Obviously there's a lot more you would want to store in this table.

```
customers
    id              unsigned int(P)
    user_id         unsigned int(F users.id)
    ...

+----+---------+-----+
| id | user_id | ... |
+----+---------+-----+
|  1 |       2 | ... |
|  2 |       3 | ... |
| .. | ....... | ... |
+----+---------+-----+
```

The same customer can be associated with many different tenants and each tenant can have many different customers, this table ties them together. Each column is a foreign key to it's respective table and together they form the primary key for the table. In my example data we see that `Mary` is a customer of `Barbie's Hair Salon` as well as `Ken's Gym` and `Greg` is a customer of `Ken's Gym`.

```
customers_tenants
    customer_id     unsigned int(F customers.id)--\_(P)
    tenant_id       unsigned int(F tenants.id)----/

+-------------+-----------+
| customer_id | tenant_id |
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |         1 |
|           2 |         2 |
|           1 |         2 |
| ........... | ......... |
+-------------+-----------+
```

What you call staff is what I would call employees, these are people who work for a tenant. In my example data we see that `Bob` and `Mary` both work for `Barbie's Hair Salon` and `Greg` works at `Ken's Gym`.

```
employees (staff)
    id              unsigned int(P)
    user_id         unsigned int(F users.id)
    sin             unsigned int // Social Insurance Number
    dob             date // Date of birth
    hired           date
    ...

+----+---------+-----------+------------+------------+-----+
| id | user_id | sin       | dob        | hired      | ... |
+----+---------|-----------+------------+------------+-----+
|  1 |       1 | 123456789 | 1995-01-01 | 2013-12-13 | ... |
|  2 |       2 | 987654321 | 1996-01-01 | 2013-10-30 | ... |
|  3 |       3 | 123459876 | 1994-01-01 | 2013-01-24 | ... |
| .. | ....... | ......... | .......... | .......... | ... |
+----+---------|-----------+------------+------------+-----+
```

We need a table that ties employees and tenants together. This table is very similar to the `customers_tenants` table. In my example data we see that `Bob` works at `Ken's Gym` and `Mary` works at both `Barbie's Hair Salon` and `Ken's Gym`.

```
employees_tenants
    employee_id     unsigned int(F employees.id)
    tenant_id       unsigned int(F tenants.id)

+-------------+-----------+
| employee_id | tenant_id |
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |         2 |
|           2 |         1 |
|           2 |         2 |
| ........... | ......... |
+-------------+-----------+
```

In the `tenants` table we store information about each tenant. Obviously you will have much more than just a name.

```
tenants
    id                  unsigned int(P)(F users.id)
    name                varchar(50)
    ...

+----+---------------------+-----+
| id | name                | ... |
+----+---------------------+-----+
|  1 | Barbie's Hair Salon | ... |
|  2 | Ken's Gym           | ... |
| .. | ................... | ... |
+----+---------------------+-----+
```

And finally we have a table with user information. Since `customers` and `employees` are subsets of `users` we store all common information such as first_name, last_name, etc. here.

```
users
    id              unsigned int(P)
    username        varchar(32)
    password        varbinary(255)
    first_name      varchar(30)
    last_name       varchar(30)
    ...

+----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----+
| id | username | password | first_name | last_name | ... |
+----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----+
|  1 | bob      | ******** | Bob        | Sled      | ... |
|  2 | mary     | ******** | Mary       | Poppins   | ... |
|  3 | greg     | ******** | Greg       | Stamps    | ... |
|  4 | jen      | ******** | Jennifer   | Jones     | ... |
| .. | ........ | ........ | .......... | ......... | ... |
+----+----------+----------+------------+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: i like your answer but i have a little question concerning the "customers"table. It seems to me that the customers table cannot carry additional information/fields because customers belongs to a specific company and any information about the customer and specific company will be in the "customers_tenants" table and as   such the "users" table can be used in the join table instead of creating additional customers table. Can you clarify why the customers table is necessary?