# Multi-Tenant Database Design - Staff and Customers Can Belong To Multiple Tenants

Tags: sql, database, database-design, multi-tenant

I'm designing a multi-tenant application and have read this post [Is this multi-tenant database design is good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214547/is-this-multi-tenant-database-design-is-good) concerning multi-tenant database design. The post emphasises the fact that a customer or staff can belong to multiple different tenants. I really enjoyed the answer given by user: **Benny Hill** and like the table design but am struggling with the importance of the `customers` table.

The foreign-key in the `customers` table links to the `users` table which contains for instance the first and last names of the user and other user specific information.

It appears to me that any specific information (eg: date_joined, date_left, etc...) about a customer and a particular tenant will be stored in the join table (`customers_tenants`)

It also appears to me that no additional information can be stored in the `customers` table because the `customers` table is about the customer alone and have no connection to a tenant. I can't think from the top of my head any relevant information/data that can be stored in the customers table which will be relevant to all the multiple tenants a customer is member of. Maybe someone can prove me wrong.

My conclusion is that the `customers` table is not needed. The customer in the join table `customers_tenants` can be replaced directly with the user from the `users` table. I don't see the need of the `customers` table at all.

I hope someone can clarify to me why the customers table is important.

Comment: Please put everything & only what you need to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Posts should be self-contained. Don't expect readers to read all of another page & guess what is related to your post & why. [ask] [Help] PS There is no question in this post.

Answer (score 0):

The customers details table is still needed.

What is unneeded though is the details of the customers (date_joined, date_left, etc...) being repeated on the join table `customers_tenants`
as long as it is a one to many table the details shouldn't be repeated in each row for better performance.

Comment: "@Nawras:" can you explain why the customers table is needed? Since a customer can belong to multiple tenants you can't put customer details in the customers table. If you want to do that then you have to create a new customer record for each tenant and the customer table must also have tenant_id column. I think every detail of a customer-and-tenant (date_joined, date_left, etc..) relation should be put in the customers_tenants table and the customer table becomes redundant. 
I want to know the real reason why the customer table is needed.

Comment: So you don't have any particular information about the customer himself like phone number social security number...etc?

Comment: "@Nawras" i presume that those info will be stored in the users table where you store his first and last names and not in the customers table

Comment: Typically such DB goes like this:
Customer table: Name, Address ,Phone number ....etc.
Tenant table :Name, Property, Address....etc. 
Customer-tenant table: with PK and FK of both of the prev tables which could be many to many
So if the user table is having all the required info of the customer then yes it is redundant.